# Memory blocks and tags

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Suppose that we have a cpu with cache that consists of 128 blocks. 8 bytes of memory can be saved to each block.How can I find which block each address belongs to? Also what is each address' tag?

The following is my way of thinking.

Take the 32bit address 1030 for example. If I do 1030 * 4 = 4120 I have the address in a byte format. Then I turn it in a 8byte format 4120 / 8 = 515.

Then I do 515 % 128 = 3 which is (8byte address)%(number of blocks) to find the block that this address is on (block no.3).

Then I do 515 / 128 = 4 to find the possition that the address is on block no.3. So tag = 4.

Is my way of thinking correct?
Any comment is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

What we know generically:

- A cache decomposes addresses into fields, namely: a tag field, an index field, and a block offset field.  For any given cache the field sizes are fixed, and, knowing their width (number of bits) allows us decompose an address the same way that cache does.

An address as a simple number:

```
+---------------------------+
|          address          |
+---------------------------+
```

We would view addresses as unsigned integers, and the number of bits used for the address is the address space size.  As decomposed into fields by the cache:

```
+----------------------------+
|    tag    | index | offset |
+----------------------------+
```

Each field uses an integer number of bits for its width.

What we know from your problem statement:

- the block size is 8 bytes, therefore

  - the block offset field width is log<sub>2</sub>( block size in bytes )
- the address space (total number of bit in an address) is 32 bits, therefore

  - tag width + index width + offset width = 32

Since information about associativity is not given we should assume the cache is direct mapped.  No information to the contrary is provided, and direct mapped caches are common early in coursework.  I'd verify or else state the assumption explicitly of direct mapped cache.

- there are 128 blocks, therefore, for a direct mapped cache

  - there are 128 index positions in the cache array.
  - (for 2- way or 4- way we would divide by 2 or 4, respectively)
- Given 128 index positions in the cache array

  - the index field width is log<sub>2</sub>( number of index positions )
- Knowing the index field width, the block offset field width, and total address width, we can compute the tag field width

  - tag field width = 32 - index field width - block offset field width

Only when you have such field widths does it make sense to attempt to decode a given address and extract the fields' actual values for that address.

Because there are three fields, the preferred approach to extraction is to simply write out the address in binary and group the bits according to the fields and their widths.

(Division and modulus can be made to work but with (a) 3 fields, and (b) the index field being in the middle using math there is a arguable more complex, since to get the index we have to divide (to remove the block offset) and modulus (to remove the tag bits), but this is equivalent to the other approach.)

---

Comments on your reasoning:

1. You need to know if 1030 is in decimal or hex.  It is unusual to write an addresses in decimal notation, since hex notation converts into binary notation (and hence the various bit fields) so much easier.  (Some educational computers use decimal notation for addresses, but they generally have a much smaller address space, like 3 decimal digits, and certainly not a 32-bit address space.)
2. > Take the 32bit address 1030 for example. If I do 1030 * 4 = 4120 I have the address in a byte format.

   Unless something is really out of the ordinary, the address 1030 is already in byte format — so don't do that.
3. > Then I turn it in a 8byte format 4120 / 8 = 515.

   The 8 bytes of the cache make up the block offset field for decoding an address.  Need to decode the address into 3 fields, not necessarily divide it.

Again the key is to first compute the block size, then the index size, then the tag size.  Take a given address, convert to binary, and group the bits to know the tag, index, and block offset values in binary (then maybe convert those values to hex (or decimal if you must)).